# ConcurrentSkipListMap how to make remove and add calls atomic

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I have N threads that add values and one removing thread. I am thinking of the best way how to sync adding to existing list of values and removing of the list.

I guess following case is possible:

```
 thread 1 checked condition containsKey, and entered in else block
 thread 2 removed the value
 thread 1 try to add value to existing list, and get returns null
```

I think the only approach that I can use is syncing by map value, in our case is List when we adding and when we deleting

```
    private ConcurrentSkipListMap<LocalDateTime, List<Task>> tasks = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

    //Thread1,3...N
    public void add(LocalDateTime time, Task task) {
        if (!tasks.containsKey(time)) {
            tasks.computeIfAbsent(time, k -> createValue(task));
        } else {
             //potentially should be synced
            tasks.get(time).add(task);
        }
    }
    private List<Task> createValue(Task val) {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(val));
    }

    //thread 2
   public void remove()
    while(true){
        Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, List<Task>> keyVal = tasks.firstEntry();
        if (isSomeCondition(keyVal)) {
            tasks.remove(keyVal.getKey());
            for (Task t : keyVal.getValue()) {
                //do task processing
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Do you need `ConcurrentSkipListMap` specifically? `ConcurrentHashMap` has atomicity guarantees for operations like `compute` and `computeIfAbsent` which could be very useful here.

Comment: @shmosel i guess so because i want to store my records ordered by LocalDateTime

Comment: @shmosel it's not clear to me what CHM guarantees actually help you here compared to CSLM.

Comment: I sure hope I'm wrong but there is nothing that I am aware of that would fit to your needs, without external/additional synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not entirely clear what your `remove()` method is supposed to do. In its current form, it’s an infinite loop, first, it will iterate over the head elements and remove them, until the condition is not met for the head element, then, it will repeatedly poll for that head element and re-evaluate the condition. Unless, it manages to remove all elements, in which case it will bail out with an exception.

If you want to process all elements currently in the map, you may simply loop over it, the weakly consistent iterators allow you to proceed while modifying it; you may notice ongoing concurrent updates or not.

If you want to process the matching head elements only, you have to insert a condition to either, return to the caller or put the thread into sleep (or better add a notification mechanism), to avoid burning the CPU with a repeated failing test (or even throw when the map is empty).

Besides that, you can implement the operations using `ConcurrentSkipListMap` when you ensure that there is no interference between the functions. Assuming `remove` is supposed to process all current elements once, the implementation may look like

```
public void add(LocalDateTime time, Task task) {
    tasks.merge(time, Collections.singletonList(task),
        (l1,l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(),l2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

public void remove() {
    for(Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, List<Task>> keyVal : tasks.entrySet()) {
        final List<Task> values = keyVal.getValue();
        if(isSomeCondition(keyVal) && tasks.remove(keyVal.getKey(), values)) {
            for (Task t : values) {
                //do task processing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key point is that the lists contained in the map are never modified. The `merge(time, Collections.singletonList(task), …` operation will even store an immutable list of a single task if there was no previous mapping. In case there are previous tasks, the merge function `(l1,l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(),l2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())` will create a new list rather than modifying the existing ones. This may have a performance impact when the lists become much larger, especially when the operation has to be repeated in the case of contention, but that’s the price for not needing lock nor additional synchronization.

The `remove` operation uses the `remove(key, value)` method which only succeeds if the map’s value still matches the expected one. This relies on the fact that neither of our methods ever modifies the lists contained in the map, but replaces them with new list instances when merging. If `remove(key, value)` succeeds, the list can be processed; at this time, it is not contained in the map anymore. Note that during the evaluation of `isSomeCondition(keyVal)`, the list is still contained in the map, therefore, `isSomeCondition(keyVal)` *must not* modify it, though, I assume that this should be the case for a testing method like `isSomeCondition` anyway. Of course, evaluating the list within `isSomeCondition` also relies on the other methods never modifying the list.

Comment: is it possible for this call keyVal.getValue() to have outdated value? For example we obtained values = keyVal.getValue() in remove; next in parallel was called add() that will add one more value and produce new list; in this moment we have old values in the values list and we do iteration only by them but remove all list

Comment: @Sergey: `keyVal.getValue()` may receive an outdated value, but in that case, the subsequent `remove(keyVal.getKey(), values)` will fail as the values do not match, hence, no action will be taken. The `remove()` loop only processes values, if that `remove` operation succeeds, in which case a subsequent `add` operation will see the key as absent and not “add one more value”, but rather create a new list.

Answer (score 3):

About the `add` part you *would* be really inclined to use `merge`, but the documentation is pretty clear about it - saying that it is not guaranteed to happen atomically.

I would replace your `add` with `merge`, but *under a lock*.

```
SomeLock lock ... 
public void add(LocalDateTime time, Task task) {
    lock.lock();
    tasks.merge...
    lock.unlock();
}
```

And same for the `remove` method. But then, if you are doing things under a lock there is no need for `ConcurrentSkipListMap` in the first place.

On the other hand if you are OK changing to `ConcurrentHashMap` - it has `merge` that is atomic for example.

Comment: hah) so I think I need to replace it with simple TreeMap. By the way in case my key will be not List but single Object, I guess CSLM will not require syncing, what do you think?

Comment: in this case i don't understand why do we need it at all

Comment: sorry i mean ConcurrentSkipListMap

Comment: it is only useful when keys are different

Comment: @Sergey if I understood you correctly you mean having `ConcurrentSkipListMap<LocalDateTime, String>` for example and performing operations on it like `put, remove` etc? Of course these operations are thread-safe as documentation explicitly says it. Or do you mean something else that I'm not following?

Comment: yes I am talking about this case. Is it not possible for thread1  to miss adding task because if (!tasks.containsKey(time)) will say task is inside but thread2 will remove it with tasks.remove()  in parallel?

Comment: @Sergey that's the point. `ConcurrentSkipListMap` *individual* operations are thread safe, when you *chain* them - `containsKey -> computeIfAbsent `, you now have a race condition obviously.

Comment: But of course, `containsKey` is entirely obsolete when using `computeIfAbsent`. When you use either, one of the `compute…` methods or `merge`, without a redundant pre-test, the only problem is the racy modification of the already contained value, which can be solved, but not without a price…